# Duplicate symbol __instance

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

Duplicate symbol during linking phase was covered here several times. But i found no answer for this case:

I have own library writen in c++ for objective-c app. To use c++ logic from lib i have change file extension from `.m` to `.mm` wich works like a charm. Problems begins when i want to have more than one `.mm` file. Linker throws at me error `duplicate symbol __instance in:` and `ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386`.

- I haven't used or declared symbol `__instance` anywhere in c++ code.
- I dont need to use or import c++ code to get this errors.
- There's no duplicated files in compile sources phase
- Every target in project has set iOS architecture, not i386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in incorrect implementation of `instance` method in one class.